# network loop detection in network

Tags: networking, vxworks, rtos

I have a network application which uses Vxworks TCP stack. Here if we have network loop in network.
I am aware of network loop causes broad cast storm. How do I detect this programmatically?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can't (really). Your application using TCP is above layer 4.

A bridge loop is a layer 2 configuration issue and needs to be dealt with on the layer 2 level i.e. on the involved switches. The most common method is to implement the rapid spanning tree protocol (RSTP).

(You can check the system counters for broadcasts and examine the frequency, everything above a certain frequency can be considered broadcast storm.)

Answer (score 0):

HP Switches Detect Network Loops automatically. Once it's found a loop it blocks it for ten minutes and then unblocks it. It does this until it is resolved